# Git remove files on server that not in repository

Tags: git

In my git source I have a folder where script save uploaded files. Repo placed on production server. On push git remove files in this folder, because its not in repository. How I can fix it?

---

In repository there are `upload` folder, that contains one hidden file. In production `php` script place in this folder files uploaded by users. When I do `git push` after modifications in source, git clean this folder in production.

Comment: Add the script folder to your `.gitignore` file so git will ignore it?

Comment: Store the files outside the git repository.

Comment: **Gary Fixler**, yes folder `upload` in `.gitignore` file

Comment: **asmeurer**, I can't do this, because this is not my server. Hoster create repository automatically. I just clone this and modify.

Comment: Even I save files outside the git repository how can I access its from web (web root in repository)?

Comment: I find a special folder on server for store user data )))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve problem by saving files outside the repository (as say **asmeurer**) and create symlink `upload` instead of folder in repository. For use different symlinks in local and remote repository I add `upload` to `.gitignore` and do `git update-index --assume-unchanged` for this file.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want those files in same repo and you dont want to move them to another folder then do not add them in git.. dont use git add  for those files... Now you want to remove them copy those files to another folder . run git rm file_name and then copy paste them in same folder in this way git doesnt care about your untracked files..

Comment: yes then you can simple mergeyour changes for which you have resolved merge conflicts by  " git rm ".. It will delete those files from remote.

Comment: Files I need do keep placed on server and there are not in repository.  So when I do `git push` git removes this files.